# How can i get header from request and set it to pytest environment?

Tags: python-3.x, request, pycharm, pytest

I was set for task to write small autotest API. (even though I am a manual junior tester).

The function is:

```
def test_post_tokens
```

In this post request I need to get authrization-header from response.

Next I need to pick up this token and insert it into other requests. (or set it to pytest environment). For example:

```
def test_get_account_info
```

It is possible to manually set a token for each request, but it takes a lot of time and the hunt to do everything correctly.

In postman, I solved this problem by getting a token in the first request and setting it in an environment

```
pm.environment.set ("token", postman.getResponseHeader ("Auth-Token"));
```

Comment: You can write a fixture that makes the `POST` request, extracts the token from the response and returns it, then use the fixture in both `test_post_tokens` and `test_get_account_info`.